Cookie auth (identity) for MAUI Blazor (BlazorWebView)?
I cannot find answer to simple question.
They say for not browser devices use token based auth. What about MAUI Blazor with BlazorWebView? Can cookie auth be used for login and persist cookie or only token based auth?
Thank you.

In a MAUI Blazor application using BlazorWebView, you can use either token-based authentication or cookie-based authentication, either of them, depending on your requirements and the nature of your application. Has your approach failed in any way? edit your question if so

I have not tied because I dont have Mac and also dont have android phone. Of course its not a problem to get one I just want to know before getting all those thing if its even possible to do it this way so I can save some time. Will Identity auth work with ios and adroid (both MAUI Blazor) normally as it wold with WASM client? Can IOS and Android webview store persistent cookie? Do I need to twitch a code somehow or its built in? Thanks.
